# What does a p-value mean

Tags: python, pandas

I have calculated correlation using seaborn
[image]

And its p values are
[image]

What does this mean? Does it mean that the correlation calculated is repeatable and correct and we reject hypothesis that they are not correlated?

Comment: Those numbers are almost meaningless without knowing their precision. For example, is the p-value 0.001 or 0.499? That's a big difference, but both values would be consistent with your display. Could you share a slice of your data and the code that generates those tables?

Comment: If you want to know the real answer then read [Statistical tests, P values, confidence intervals, and power: a guide to misinterpretations](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10654-016-0149-3). (See 3. and 4., for example.)

Answer (score 1):

The p-value is the conditional probability given that the null hypothesis is true.

A p-value closer to zero (usually <= 0.05) is ***statistically significant enough to reject*** the notion that the null is true. Likewise, a p-value > 0.05 is not statistically significant enough, therefore you ***cannot reject*** the notion that the null is true.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow! There is one problem with your answer: "The p-value is used to tell you [...] how likely that there is no relationship between two variables." - No, this is wrong. It is one of the most common misconceptions about p-values. Actually, the p-value is calculated assuming that the null hypothesis is true, so it cannot lead to any statements about the probability of the null hypothesis. The site you link to makes the same mistake, as pointed out in a comment there.

Comment: [Essential reading regarding p-values](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10654-016-0149-3): See point 3.: "A significant test result ( P ≤ 0.05) means that the test hypothesis is false or should be rejected. No!"

Comment: @Arne thanks for pointing that out, had my words mixed up a bit there. Post has been edited to fix that.

Comment: @Spud_MD Thank you for taking the time to edit your answer. The first sentence is still wrong though. Again, **the p-value is a conditional probability, given that the null hypothesis were true**, so it is most certainly not the probability that the null hypothesis is true.